# Handling images with wrapfig - text around the image is not behaving, there must be a conflict somewhere

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I am trying to control text after inserting an image. The text is being indented like around the image long even after the image ends on the page. It's like the `\end{wrapfigure}` statement does not execute where it is inserted, but after a few text paragraphs. I don't know hoe to attach the image to this question (just 145K). And I've tried to read other posts related to `wrapfig`, none helped.
Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn,letterpaper]{article}  
% ROMANIAN CHARACTERS   
\makeatletter  
\providecommand\textcommabelow[1]  
  {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth\raise-.31ex
   \hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@ \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}  \egroup}  

\newcommand{\cS}{\textcommabelow S}  
\newcommand{\cs}{\textcommabelow s}  
\newcommand{\cT}{\textcommabelow T}  
\newcommand{\ct}{\textcommabelow t}  
% \cs\ \cS \ct\ \cT \^a \^A \u a \u A  \^\i\  \^I  
% END ROMANIAN CHARACTERS  

\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{wrapfig}  
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}  
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\everymath{\displaystyle}  
\doublespacing  

\begin{document}

\large

\textbf{Solu\ct ie problema 6.}\\

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8.00 cm} \hspace*{-0.5cm}\includegraphics[height=100mm]{R1_01_P06.jpg} \end{wrapfigure}  

\hspace*{1.0cm} Lu\u am punctele $A$ \cs i $B$ astfel \^inc\^at $A$ s\u a fie mai aproape de axa $Oy$ \cs i $B$  s\u a fie mai aproape de axa $Ox$\, (vezi figura). Not\u am coordonatele astfel: $A( x_{A}\,,\, y_{A} )$ \cs i $B( x_{B}\,,\, y_{B} )$\,.\\
\hspace*{1.0cm} Construim apoi simetricele lui $A$ \cs i $B$ fa\ct \u a de axele $Ox$ \cs i $Oy$ \cs i ob\ct inem punctele $A'$ \cs i $B'$\,.\\

\hspace*{3.0cm}\begin{minipage}[t]{6.5cm}
$A'$ este simetricul lui $A$ fa\ct \u a de axa $Oy$\,,\, iar $B'$ este simetricul lui $B$ fa\ct \u a de axa $Ox$\,. 
Observ\u am c\u a avem deci coordonatele $( x_{B}\,,\, - y_{B})$ pentru $B'$ \cs i $( - x_{A} \,,\, y_{A} )$ pentru $A'$\,.\\[1.0cm]
\end{minipage}


\hspace*{1.0cm} Unim punctele $A'$ \cs i $B'$ printr-un segment de dreapt\u a \cs i not\u am cu $M$ intersec\ct ia segmentului $A'B'$ cu axa $Oy$\,,\, \cs i cu $N$ intersec\ct ia segmentului $A'B'$ cu axa $Ox$\,. Se observ\u a c\u a $A'M \,=\, AM$ \cs i $A'M_{2} \,=\, AM_{2}$ \cs i $A'M_{1} \,=\, AM_{1}$\,,\, egalitate care este adev\u arat\u a pentru orice punct de pe axa $Ox$ \^in raport cu punctele $A$ \cs i $A'$\,.\, La fel, se observ\u a c\u a $B'N \,=\, BN$ \cs i $B'N_{2} \,=\, BN_{2}$ \cs i $B'N_{1} \,=\, BN_{1}$\,,\, egalitate care este adev\u arat\u a pentru orice punct de pe axa $Oy$ \^in raport cu punctele $B$ \cs i $B'$\,.\\

Where is this text indented and why???\\

Where is this text indented and why???\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not compile for me. However, if the automatic calculation of the number of lines that should be shortened to accommodate the figure is wrong, you can manually specify it in the first optional argument to the `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[20]{r}{5cm} \ldots \end{wrapfigure}
```

would shorten exactly 20 lines.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice worked!! I have no idea why line-height is such an obscure parameter, you are the first one to mention it to me - again, thanks a million! Colin